# Report viewer doesn't display the report i assigned

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reporting

I am new in using ReportViewer in C#. I am trying to display the report I made using crystal reports.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("C:Users\\Document\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

This is the error message:

```
'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I already add the reference **Interop.CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib10**

How can I solve this?

Comment: You forgot to add opening quote at load command

Answer (score 1):

You need  to add 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine as reference to make your program work.

[CrystalReportViewer Control in Visual Studio 2010](http://www.blog.mudasar.co.uk/?p=33)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding CrystalDecisions.ReportSource Library. And also, which version CR are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this assembly microsoft.reportviewer.winforms.dll is added to your project.